# Update in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have to update a field in a table. I'm using following queries. Help me, which one is right?

```
update table1
set col1=<value>,col2=<value>....
from table1 t,table2 s
where t.id=s.num
  and s.code='abc';
```

or

```
update table1
set col1=<value>,col2=<value>....
where table1.id=table2.num
  and table2.code='abc';
```

Which one is right? Or both are incorrect? Please suggest some way...

Answer (score 8):

Neither is correct.  It's not clear from your fragment what you are trying to do, but the syntax to update one table with values from another would be more like:

```
update table1
set (col1, col2) =
( select col1, col2
  from   table2
  where  table2.num = table1.id
  and    table2.code = 'abc'
)
where table1.id in (select num from table2);
```

The final WHERE clause is to prevent updating all non-matched table1 rows with nulls.

Another method that works when table1 is ["key preserved"](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:189379506317175::::P11_QUESTION_ID:548422757486) in the query is:

```
update
( select table1.id, table1.col1, table1.col2
  ,      table2.col1 as new_col1, table2.col as new_col2
  from   table1
         join table2 on table2.num = table1.id
)
set col1 = new_col1, col2 = new_col2;
```

Answer (score 5):

```sql
MERGE
INTO table1 t1
USING (
 SELECT *
 FROM table2
 WHERE table2.code = 'abc'
) t2
ON (t1.id = t2.num)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET col1 = t2.value1, col2 = t2.value2
```

**Remember to always qualify the SET statement, ie t2.value1**. No error is thrown when ambiguous. In other words, **SET col1 = value1** would be **t2.value1**, but would be **t1.value1** if **t2.value1** was missing.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your last remark, you need to update table table1 with fixed values that are not in a database table.
But only for rows in table1 that match with specific rows in table 2. 
In that case you can use this statement:

```
update table1 t1
set t1.col1='value',
t1.col2='value2',
t1.col3='value3'
where exists ( select ''
               from table2 s 
               where  t1.id=s.num 
               and s.code='abc'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following query:

```
update (select col1 from table1 t inner join table2 s
on t.id=s.num where s.code='abc') t1
set t1.col1='value';
```

it worked fine..

But when I used it for updating multiple cols, it produced an error:

> *Missing right parenthesis.*

Could you help...

```
update (select col1,col2,col3 from table1 t inner join table2 s
on t.id=s.num where s.code='abc') t1
set t1.col1='value',t1.col2='value2',t1.col3='value3';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to add values on click event of button1. I have used the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    val = TextBox1.Text

    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        rcvd = RadioButton1.Text
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        rcvd = RadioButton2.Text
    End If

    If RadioButton5.Checked = True Then
        type = RadioButton5.Text
    ElseIf RadioButton6.Checked = True Then
        type = RadioButton6.Text
    ElseIf RadioButton7.Checked = True Then
        type = RadioButton8.Text
    ElseIf RadioButton9.Checked = True Then
        type = RadioButton9.Text
    ElseIf RadioButton10.Checked = True Then
        type = RadioButton10.Text
    End If

    Try

        XXX = "update(select rcvd,amount,instype,chq,ucode,uname,remarks from fapark04 f inner join sumast04 s on f.party=s.account where s.abnmn=' " & val & " ' ) fa set fa.rcvd=' " & rcvd & " ', fa.amount= " & TextBox5.Text & " ,fa.instype='" & type & " ',fa.chq= " & TextBox9.Text & " ,fa.ucode=' " & TextBox12.Text & "',fa.uname='" & TextBox13.Text & "',fa.remarks='" & TextBox14.Text & "' "

        cmd1 = New OracleCommand(XXX, con)
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("A Run time error occured!!!", ex.ToString)

    End Try

End Sub
```

This does not updates the rows but when same query is fired at the backend it updates the rows.

When updated from front end it shows 0 rows updated. Why is it so??

help..

Answer (score -1):

In your query, you are using two tables in where clause condition. So you have to either join or subquery or merge type, use so that u can get correct output